# Stacked detuned voices sound different in Synthmaster compared to Serum

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer

I tried to recreate the sound from this tutorial here

(1:58). It's essentially a Sawtooth with 16 voices, somehow detuned and spread out in stereo, done in Serum.

Doing this in Synthmaster I don't quite get the same result. Instead there is a high pitched "flanging" sound sitting on top:

Here is a sustained example:

You can hear a sharp squeal and then iterates through overtones somehow.

This is how the relevant parameters look like in Synthmaster:

[image]

What is this "extra sound" and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Sounds like you have a resonant filter closing down in the release phase; but as I don't know either piece of software I have no clue where you'd find it.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not about the release. I added a sustained example. You can hear it right from the start.

Comment: Then it's in the decay too & the filter envelope is not tied to the amplitude envelope.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand what you mean now. Can't find anything of the sorts though.

Comment: See http://www.kv331audio.com/synthmaster/downloads/synthmasterusermanual.pdf I've never used it, so I've not a clue where anything is in it.

Comment: Didn't think I would find anything there, but I did actually find it after all.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You need to turn on "FREE" (like in this picture). From the manual:

> **Free:** Controls whether the oscillator waveform(s) start at a random phase, similar to free-running analog
> synthesizer oscillators. This is especially useful when voices parameter is increased to create “SuperSaw”
> type sounds.

So the issue here is that all 16 voices had the same phase, which together with the detune created this flanging sound.

Comment: Glad you figured it. I hadn't considered phasing/flanging due to identical waveforms all starting in the same place with different speeds.